# failed to run hive queries in parallel using hue query editor

Tags: hive, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, hue, impala

I have cdh-5 cluster with hive, impala and hue installed.

When 2 users try to use in parallel the Hue "Query Editor" with either Impala or Hive, we never get the result back. 
When a single user fires a query we get results without a problem
When we tried to user Hive command line interface we could run queries in parallel.
We also tried to create different hue users, but even when different hue users tried to run queries in parallel we still got no result

It looks like hue configuration issue.

Any ideas?

Yosi

Comment: Are you using the default embedded SQLite? You are probably having some concurrent DB calls that deadlocks. Are you seeing 'Database locked' in the Hue logs or Chrome network console? The recommended setup is to use an external DB like MySql http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_hue_database.html#concept_id1_wkj_zj_unique_1

Comment: No, I am using MySql